# pipe 2 linux commands in C

Tags: c, homework

I am writing a simpel program that can basicly do the same as piping two linux commands can do. For example, `ls -l | grep vars.sh`, this can be done on the Linux console. I need to write a programm in C that can do the same. I think I got it working but I want to know if I am doing it rite and if there are some modifications I can do on my code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // Voor verschillende I/O's, macro's, declaraties.
#include <stdlib.h> // Om de system call te activeren.
#include <unistd.h> // Laden van constanten en types.

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);
    pid = fork();

    if(pid==-1){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pid>0){
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1],1);
        execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL);
    }
    else{
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0],0);
        execlp("grep","grep",".bashrc",NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Any feedback,rewrites or modifications are welcome.

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: Code looks fine, not entirely clear what your question is.

Comment: Looks like you are doing it rite :-)

Comment: Yea a homework problem :) I just want to be able to do `command | command` that works on Linux in a C program. The code works, but is there another way to do it by modifying the code? As in can this be done in a other way with C?

Comment: There are a [number of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe+c) for essentially the same problem (one of them yours from yesterday - though you have indubitably improved your question this time compared with that one; thank you), many with answers.  Which of them did you review to see how your code differs from the working solutions?

Comment: You don't do nearly enough plumbing; you need to close a lot more pipe file descriptors.  If you `dup2()` a descriptor, you normally want to close the starting descriptor afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way that I could see this can be done in POSIX would be to use `popen()` rather than using raw pipes.  It also returns a stream pointer that can be used with the C standard I/O functions like `fprintf()`, `fgets()`, etc. to read and/or write to the process on the other-side of the pipe created by `popen()`.  According to the POSIX specification, with `popen()`,

> The environment of the executed
>   command shall be as if a child process
>   were created within the popen() call
>   using the fork() function, and the
>   child invoked the sh utility using the
>   call:
>
> execl(shell path, "sh", "-c", command,
>   (char *)0);
>
> where shell path is an unspecified
>   pathname for the sh utility.

So it's basically an easier, more straight-forward way to work with pipes rather than having to fork child processes yourself and close the un-used portions of the pipe so that you don't end up with accidental blocking reads or lost writes because there are still active file-descriptors on each end of the pipe that you've accidentally forgotten to close in either the parent or child process.

With your example, using `popen()` would look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 128

FILE *ls_proc, *grep_proc;
ls_proc = popen("ls -l", "r");
grep_proc = popen("grep .bashrc", "w");

char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

//read from one child process and write to the other
while (fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, ls_proc) != NULL)
    fprintf(grep_proc, "%s", buffer);

pclose(ls_proc);
pclose(grep_proc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though if I copy paste this in a main () function I get all sorts of errors when compiling. the FILE* gives an error and the fprintf statement gives a error

Comment: Sorry, a small typo in the declaration of `grep_proc` where I forgot its `*` symbol because it's a pointer to a stream.  You can copy and paste this code now and it should work.

Comment: This will not work with binary data that is passed through the pipe.`fgets` and `fprintf` only work on null terminal strings. Also, this requires the parent process to do the actual transfer of data in the `while` loop while the original example does not need a `while` loop to transfer data from one process to another (the system does the work for you).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. Since you're asking, I'd suggest one tiny thing; that you check the calls return values. pipe() and dup2() can fail too, you want to know when that happens.